# method level custom annotation doesn't work spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-aop

I am trying to define custom annotation(LogMe) that should run before and after methods that are decorated with the annotation.
The annotation works fine for the spring identified methods - the ones defined with @GetMapping etc. however, the annotation on my custom written methods doesn't invoke AOP.

I have defined annotation as follows:

```java
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LogMe {
```

My Aspect is like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Aspect
public class LogMeAspect {


    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.api.logging.aspect.LogMe)")
    public void loggableMethods() {}


    @Around("loggableMethods()")
    public Object serviceResponseTimeAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>REACHING TO PJP:"+joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        Object obj = joinPoint.proceed();
        return obj;
    }

}
```

spring.factories defined as follows (I am trying to access this aspect from dependency).

```java
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
com.api.logging.aspect.LoggingAspect,\
com.api.logging.aspect.LogMeAspect
```

usage of the annotation:

```java
public class Utils {
    @LogMe
    public String testing(int i, int j, String str) {
        System.out.println("in testing");
        testing2();
        return i+j+str;
    }

    @LogMe
    public void testing2() {
        System.out.println("in testing 2");
    }
```

I have the following dependencies for my aspect module.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-json-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.contrib.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.contrib.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.13</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>6.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have following dependencies for the module from where I am calling the aspect. of course, one of it is the aspect dependency - spring-boot-api-logging

```xml
        <!-- core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- matrix -->

        <!-- kafka -->

        <!-- tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- logging-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.api.commons.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-api-logging</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: AOP is proxy based and will only work for method calls into the object not internal methods. Also as it is proxy based it will only work on spring managed instances, so if you do `new Util();` and expect it to work it won't as it isn't managed by Spring.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, thanks for the response. please can you let me know what is the most effective way to achieve my requirement if AOP is not an option then ?

Comment: You can use AOP but you will have to resort to full blown Aspectj with either load or compile time weaving.

Comment: If you throw AspectJ libraries into your POM, you should also find out first which one has which purpose. And maybe you could decide which version you want. Presently, you use runtime 1.7.4, weaver 1.8.13 and tools 1.9.6. "Much helps much" is not a good strategy. Furthermore, because weaver is a superset of runtime and tools a superset of weaver, you have different versions of the same class files on the classpath. This reminds me of playing Russian Roulette.

Comment: ...or you can make `Utils` a bean